# When talking about gradient $\nabla f(x)$ are we assume $f(x)$ is scalar valued?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Previously I always thought $\nabla f(x)$ is just the transpose of $Df(x)$. But recently I noticed that I wasn't able to find $\nabla f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is vector value function in my reference. Is it widely accepted that $\nabla f(x)$ should be scalar valued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the notation is reserved for the gradient of a suitable map $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$. If a map with its codomain $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ where $m \geq 2$ is a given integer, then the concept of Jacobian matrix takes place instead. And the Jacobian matrix of a map $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ where $n \geq 1$ and $m \geq 2$ are given integers, if it exists, can be denoted by $Df$.